# How to get the image url from RSS feed?

Tags: swift, xcode, rss, imageurl

I'm using an MWFeed (Objective-C feed parser from GitHub ) and I'm trying to access the image from the articles in my feed . So far I've wrote this :

```
let item =  feedItems[indexPath.row] as MWFeedItem?
        cell.itemImage?.layer.cornerRadius = 25.0
        cell.titleLabel.text = item?.title


        if item?.content != nil {
               let htmlContent = item!.content as NSString
               var imageSource = ""
               let rangeOfString = NSMakeRange(0, htmlContent.length)
               let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(<img.*?src=\")(.*?)(\".*?>)", options: [])
            if htmlContent.length > 0 {
                let match =  regex.firstMatch(in: htmlContent as String, options: [], range: rangeOfString)
            if match != nil {
               let imageURL = htmlContent.substring(with: match!.range(at: 2)) as NSString
                if NSString(string: imageURL.lowercased).range(of: "feedburner").location == NSNotFound {
               imageSource = imageURL as String
                }
              }
            }
            if imageSource != "" {
                cell.itemImage?.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imageSource), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "Placeholder1"))
            }
           }
```

Edit : I've found out what is wrong , `item.content is nil` , so the code never gets called ,does anyone know why `item.content = nil` and how to solve it ?
This is the feed I'm using `let url = NSURL(string: "https://sportingnews.com/rss")`

Comment: `setImageWith` is what? A third party lib? KingFisher? AlamofireImage? SDWebImage? Could you use the same method but with the completion, checking if there is an error. Also is that code even called?

Comment: the code is called in override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

Comment: The method does not have a completion handler , I’m using SDWebImage

Comment: SDWebImage has a method with a completion block: https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage/blob/master/SDWebImage/Core/UIImageView%2BWebCache.h#L143 I know, I used it in the past.

Comment: But, what should I write in the completed area ?

Comment: You could check if there is an error for instance. That's a good start, no?